# Why not to use "vertical-align: top;" instead of "display: block;" on <img> in emails?

Tags: email, html-email

This pattern:
`<img src="path/to/image.png" width="420" height="130" style="display: block; border: none;">`
has become common, now it is sort of best practice. I see this is every article and in every project.

If I understand correctly `display: block;` is being used to remove few pixels of empty space under the image caused by the fact that `<img>` is aligned to baseline by default.

But why not to use `vertical-align: top;` then? This is more straightforward in the code and it doesn't cause confuses when `display` property needed for responsiveness:[image: f]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `vertical-align:top` is a substitute for `display:block` in the `<img>` tag. They achieve the same result.

I tested, via Litmus, Desktop applications: Apple Mail 13, IBM Notes 10, Outlook 2010, Outlook 2019, Windows 10 Mail, Thunderbird 60; mobile clients: android 6 native, Gmail on android, Gmail IMAP, Samsung, Outlook for Android, Gmail on iOS, Outlook iOS, iPhone 13; and webmail: Comcast, freenet.de, Gmail webmail, GMX.de, Mail.ru, Outlook.com/Office 365, T-Oline.de, Web.de, Yahoo! Mail

Testing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head> <!-- START HEAD v4-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title></title>
</head>
 <!-- END HEAD -->
    <body style="margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#ffffff;">
    <!-- START OUTER WRAPPER -->
    <center id="wrapper" class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">
        <div style="max-width:600px;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;" >
            <![endif]-->
            <table class="outer" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
            <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ff0000" style="padding:0;">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x130?text=nothing" width="120" style="border: none;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#00ff00" style="padding:0;">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x130?text=displayBlock" width="120" style="display:block;border: none;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#0000ff" style="padding:0;">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x130?text=verticalAlignTop" width="120" style="border: none;vertical-align: top">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <!-- START OUTER WRAPPER -->
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
    <!-- END OUTER WRAPPER -->
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result:

[image]

All `vertical-align:top`'s displayed as per `display:block`. On Samsung Mail (Android), each sample (i.e. all variants) had very thin outlines that I couldn't get rid of. This seemed to me to be a different issue, since `vertical-align:top` had the same tiny outline (not a border or outline) as `display:block` (and with nothing). Some sort of rendering issue related to Samsung Mail only.

Conclusion: `vertical-align:top` is a substitute for `display:block` in the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I also just run similar tests with two popular email builders with 68 and 76 configurations for testing accordingly. All good. Personally I am gonna use **vertical-align** from now on.